# Can you define an storyboard to play out, before a property changes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard

For instance I am setting the Visibility on and off for a certain element.  I have a Trigger that listens to the Visibility being set to Visible and plays out a Storyboard that fades in the element.

So on the flip side, when the element is set to Hidden, I want the element to fade out, and then have the property set to Visibility = false.  Is this possible and if so how?  Currently I have something like:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more Trigger classes that meet the eye.. Perhaps you can use another trigger to achieve what you wish to do..

From MSDN:

> There are several different types of
>   triggers: [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx), [MultiTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger.aspx),
>   [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx), [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx), and
>   [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx).

Perhaps use a DataTrigger to bind to a state property that tells the UI something is changing? Or you can try using a custom event and an EventTrigger to achieve the same? Just some thoughts..